# Recent activity shows an event occurred on the followed tab, but there's no activity to see

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, recent-activity

[image]

As a side note, the "yesterday" link points [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/recent/44?Tab=Followed&StartDate=2010-07-10&EndDate=2010-07-10) while the link on the tab itself points [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/recent/44?startdate=2010-07-10%2000%3a00%3a00z&enddate=2010-07-10%2023%3a59%3a59z&tab=followed#tab-top). Both pages exhibit the same behaviour.

I should also mention -- the summary tab is completely empty with "yesterday" selected -- it doesn't even show the +5 rep event (which *does* show in the reputation tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. (The discrepancy was caused by questions that were *edited* during the requested timeframe.)